# Group data in rdlc report

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I need to show `OrderDetails` according to the `OrderId` in the `Orders` table. Here is my DataSet:

[image: image1]

and this is my report:

[image: image2]

But this doesn't generate the result I expect. What I expect is below:

```
**Order ID     Username     Order Date**
111            abc          11/12/2013
    **Item ID   Item Name    Unit Price**
    1             item1             $10
    2             item2             $12
```

Can someone please help with designing this report? Also, do I need to make any changes in my DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

1. In RDLC report click on Row Group Properties
2. Click on sorting tab
3. Add Sort by Column Name
4. Click on Order and select A to Z OR Z to A

Option 2

1. In Sql query use order by Ordeid ASC OR DESC

Hope this will help you